# No view ID found for fragment

Tags: android

I'm aware this is a common problem and many results will pop up however I'm not finding a solution for my case... I have this view XML and I have assigned an ID:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ongoingcallfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and from the fragment I'm making sure I'm inflating this layout:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ongoing_call, container, false)
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to replace this fragment:

```
val ongoingCallFragment = OngoingCallFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString("phoneNumber", phoneNumber)
                }
            }

val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.ongoingcallfragment, ongoingCallFragment)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null) // Add to back stack for back navigation
            transaction.commit()
```

and gives the famous error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08022b (com.example.myapp:id/ongoingcallfragment) for fragment OngoingCallFragment{804e913} (1a852e7c-4f59-4ba6-b013-23c31ccbbfb4 id=0x7f08022b)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:547)
```

What am I missing?